# Issue with writing a simple matlab-function

Tags: matlab, function

I've done a few simple matlab-functions before, but for some reason unknown to me, what I'm trying to do now won't work.

The function simply looks like this:

```
function a = calc(t)
if t < 2.0
    a = -pi/2;
else
    a = 2*pi;
end
```

I try calling it by:

```
a = calc(linspace(0,5))
```

which (as I have understood it before at least) should generate a matrix of variables with the values of a. However, a simply becomes a constant with the value 2*pi. Why won't it register what happens before t >= 2? Right now it seems like it only calculates the last value (when t = 5). Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

The reason why it isn't working is because your function is only designed to output **one** value.  Naturally, MATLAB will work from the beginning of the array to the end, and so because your function only outputs one value, it will only give you the output of the **last** value in your array (a.k.a. 5).  As such, if you want to do this for a vector / matrix of values, you need to make sure that your output value `a` is also of the same type.  In other words, do something like this:

```
function a = calc(t)
a = 2*pi*ones(size(t));
a(t < 2.0) = -pi/2;
```

Let's go through this one slowly.  `a` is an array / matrix of values that is the same size as the input `t` and every value in `a` is set to `2*pi`.  After, any values where `t < 2.0`, we will change the values to `-pi/2`.  Anything else, they will stay the same (i.e. `2*pi`).  Remember, when you're working with MATLAB, you need to make sure that your output can accommodate for inputs of different shapes and sizes.  It's a different way of thinking in comparison to other programming languages that people have dealt with, but once you get the hang of it, it's really easy.

Comment: That explanation! Pretty verbose indeed :) +1

Comment: @user1742554: Please consider accepting my answer if this has helped you.  You can do this by clicking on the checkmark below the up/down arrows on the left of the top of the question.  Thanks!